# how to fix fstab of one Ubuntu from older Ubuntu in multi-boot system

Tags: home-directory, fstab, boot-repair, uuid

I have an old desktop PC (64bit) and an old laptop (32bit), on each I have 2 Windows and at least 2 Linux distros .

At the moment I have Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS installed.

After repartitioning the HDD and (or) Windows maintenance, I could only boot to windows.

So I've used a boot-repair stick to get the grub menu back.

The home and swap UUID became different from those listed in the fstab for  one Ubuntu.

I can login to Ubuntu 14.04 but not to Ubuntu 16.04.

From Ubuntu 14.04 I created new partitions for home and swap for Ubuntu 16.04 and edited the fstab to contain the new UUID. But it didn't work, I can't login to Ubuntu 16.04.

**It tries to login then comes back asking again for a password.**

I have no Ubuntu 16.04 live CD. Please help me fixing that?

Abo sal

Comment: fstab is for booting not login, are you having trouble booting or does it boot and you can't log in?

Comment: Have you tried a login in a tty or have you just tried the login from you xsession?

Comment: Can you log in on a virtual console (Ctrl+Alt+F1)?

Comment: Could that be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop ?

Comment: It boots till it reaches  user name and password, I enter name and password it try log in but it comes back to  user name and password, I use alt ctrl F1 to go to terminal and log in using  name and password the type reboot. 
I used this command to edit fstab from the  other ubuntu
sudo -i

mkdir /sparrow
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /sparrow

gedit /sparrow/etc/fstab
 save it
umount /sparrow

Comment: yes I can log in on a virtual console (Ctrl+Alt+F1)

Comment: Please enter  ls -lA and tell me the output for the file .Xauthority

Comment: To me it sounds like your user doesn't have either a home or the rights to the home are not fitting to the user anymore. Since you said you recreated the home partition that would be my guess.

Comment: @ziazis as the OP can login from the virtual console, he seems to have a home. The symptom described looks to like the (already often asked) login loop problem. https://askubuntu.com/search?q=login+loop

Comment: You can login into a virtual console even without a home, it will tell you /home/blabla not found opening instead, and still open a session. But his issue occurs exactly if the home is not reachable for the xsession.

Comment: @ziazis I guess you are right with "the rights ... are not fitting". Maybe using different userIDs for 14.04 and 16.04  Abo sal: "From Ubuntu 14.04 I created new partitions for home and swap for Ubuntu 16.04"

Comment: my problem is that after partition modification of the HDD in windows the  real UUID  Using 'blkid' doesn't  much the home UUID listed in the fstab. So I used the other ubuntu to creat the desired home and fstab using the method recomned by , Steve Stites in:

 http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/mounting-question-631370/

Comment: variona 
when typing ls – lA
I get about 20 lines that starts 
with 
drwxrwxrwt or something tlike that 
I have 2 HDD
ls -ld /tmp



drwxrwxrwt 10 root root 4096 jun 29 16:36
instead of
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp

Comment: @abosal the important thing here is if you have logged in from the virtual console into your account and you enter ls -lA do you see your directories and files AND do they belong to the user you logged in with: For example if I log in as variona a typical line would look like this: -rw-------  1 variona variona    1209 Jun 29 09:16 .Xauthority , meaning I have the right to read and write  (rw) this file.

Comment: @variona After copying the important data I intentionally deleted the old home and swap partitions (Ubuntu 16.04 ) to recover unused space at the end of the HDD, what is left is the /root partition. After  boot-repair  I used Ubuntu 14.04 to create new partitions for home and swap for Ubuntu 16.04, and modified the fsatb of Ubuntu 16.04, I used the comments of Steve Stites http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/mounting-question-631370/
 I can log into gust account. when tryping sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
I get:file or directory not found

Comment: # /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
#UUID=bf7235e3-c5d9-4961-9f93-b3caedf1cdb3 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
after delteing /home partition  UUID=bf7235e3-c5d9-4961-9f93-b3caedf1cdb3 does not exit using geparted I created new /home  UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx